# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake Support

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am trying automate android app in mac using appium (ver.1.5.3). i am getting below mentioned error. Please help.

> WebDriverException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host
>   closed connection during handshake Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info:
>   host: 'AKASHs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:84)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:90) at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:128) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72) at
>   com.test1.Test1.setUp(Test1.java:33) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645) at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851) at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177) at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756) at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133) at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104) at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236) at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
>   ... 37 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down
>   incorrectly at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
>   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
>   ... 58 more

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the URL your are using, It should not contain **https** instead use **http**. I tried it worked for me.

Comment: I tried with HTTP and it worked. Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can get information using the
openssl s_client -connect <server_name>:<port_number>
command line.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to with java as such. Check your certificates 
' OpenSSL s_client -connect <>443'

Ensure that the verify code is 0
If it's non zero ;(20) it probably means(I am guessing here) you might have a self signed certificate. That means you have to import that certificate into your java truststore.